# The class is not configured to support Elevated activation

Tags: c#, delphi

When I try to load a COM visible C#.net assembly from a Delphi application, "The class is not configured to support Elevated activation" error pops up on windows server 2012.

Is there a way to configure it to support elevated activation programmatically ?

Currently to avoid, privilege level is set to "Run as administrator".

Comment: So when does the COM function works? When your application is ran with elevated privilegies or when your application is ran as normal user' Your question isn't particulary clear on this.

Comment: The error message suggests there's more going on here. Elebated activation requires out-of-proc servers. Clearly this is so, because elevation is per process. You've not told us anything about your program. You didn't mention the use of the com elevation moniker. You didn't give any details of the com server. We need more help from you.

Answer (score 4):

That's the `CO_E_ELEVATION_DISABLED` error. It may happen if the class is not properly registered for elevation in the registry. You can find how to register it in MSDN:

[The COM Elevation Moniker](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms679687.aspx)

> The COM class must also be annotated as LUA-Enabled. This requires the following registry entry:
>
> ```
> HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Classes\CLSID
>   {CLSID}
>     Elevation
>       Enabled = 1
> ```
>
> If this entry is missing, then the activation returns the error CO_E_ELEVATION_DISABLED.
>
> Note that these entries must exist in the HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE hive, not the HKEY_CURRENT_USER or HKEY_USERS hive. This prevents users from elevating COM classes that they did not also have the privileges to register.

More info is in this blog post:

[Local elevation points in Windows and Delphi](http://www.sandon.it/?q=node/90)

Comment: New location for "Local elevation points in Windows and Delphi": https://www.sandon.it/2014/05/16/local-elevation-points-in-windows-and-delphi/